# List files not owned by root at the / directory

Tags: linux, grep, find, ls

The actual homework question is

15. List all files/directories NOT owned by root and not created in July.

I can't find a way to use

> ls

and

> grep

to output a file ~/NotOwnedByRoot.txt

```
find / \! -user root -d -maxdepth 1 -exec ls > ~/NotOwnedByRoot.txt  {} +
```

I also tried

```
find / \! -user root -type d -maxdepth 1 > ~/NotOwnedByRoot.txt
```

I get the error

> find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a
>   non-option argument !, but options are not positional (-maxdepth
>   affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after
>   it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: does "-d" want to be "-type d"? and by "list users not owned by root" did you mean "list directories not owned by root"? (guessing at the typo-corrections)

Comment: $ find / \! -user root -type d -maxdepth 1 > ~/NotOwnedByRoot.txt
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument !, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: Your title does not make sense, and does not match the 2nd line of you question. Read up on what a user, file, directory and a process is.

Comment: The error is a warning, but do what it says anyway. It will help you understand the command.

Comment: Which July? any July, or just this past one?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: The instructor doesn't care. I think he just wants to know if we can do it.

Answer (score -2):

you can use ls and grep together its very easy and with the -v in grep option you can search for words or phrases that are NOT there, so it will output everything which is not in conjunction with your search.

While in the directory you want to do this in try: **ls -l | grep -v root || July**

The first part **ls -l** lists all the files in a long listing order

The **|** symbol is called a pipe and it takes the input of the previous command and uses it as an input in the next command, in this case ls -l would be used as an input into 'grep'.

The second part **grep -v root** uses grep with the **-v** option which, with the search term root, the **-v** option is used to look for all contents that do not have what you searched for, so it will look for everything that does not have 'root'.

Finally the last part **|| July** , the **||** basically means 'and' in grep so your specifiying two or more search terms, the 'July' is the second search term.***

***PS: I DO NOT THINK THE QUESTION IS ASKING YOU TO MAKE A FILE CALLED 'NOTOWNEDBYROOT' INSTEAD ITS ASKING YOU TO SEARCH A DIRETCORY FOR ALL FILES/SUB DIRECTORYS THAT ARE NOT OWNED BY ROOT OR MADE IN JULY***

Comment: Will straight-up fail to work as intended; if `grep -v root` throws a non-zero exit code, it will attempt to run the command `July` which is very likely not to be an internal or a binary in the `PATH`.

Comment: If you fix your code, and explanation of `|` then I will change my -1 to +1

Comment: but thats what a pipe is, it takes the output of a command as an input of a next command..........

Comment: And `July` is not a command.  Things that are not the same, partial list:  `||`, `|`.  Either way, it's wrong here.

Comment: okay, what does **| |** and **|** mean then?

Comment: `||`, as you used it, has nothing to do with `grep`.  In a shell, `command1 || command2` will run `command2` if and only if the exit code from `command1` is falsy (i. e. anything other than `0`).  `command1 | command2` will run `command1`, and send its standard output into the standard input of `command2`.  Since `July` is not a command, this will fail regardless of which one you use here as presented.  If you mean `grep -vE 'root|July'`, this will fail for other reasons (e. g. a file _named_ `root` or `July`).